# Specific model for the view with MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

Let's say I want to create a WPF form. 
In this form, there are a bunch of titles and subtitles.
Theses titles and subtitles uses the same control for presentation.
This control is simply a label between a top separator and a bottom separator.
Titles must have both separator, subtitle must only have the bottom separator.
There is a boolean dependancy propertie in this control. If it set to true, there is a top separator.

Is it OK to bind this propertie in the Model for each title/subtitle?

```
public class MyModelObject : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _labelName;
    public string LabelName 
    {
        get
        {
         return _labelName;
        }
        set
        {
            _labelName=value;
            RaisePropertieChanged(()=>LabelName);
        }
    }

    private bool _topSeparator;
    public bool TopSeparator 
    {
        get
        {
         return _topSeparator;
        }
        set
        {
            _topSeparator=value;
            RaisePropertieChanged(()=>TopSeparator);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like it much... Since a Model should have no information about the view. But is there a clean way to do it?

I was thinking about a specific Model for the view... But I'm not sure about it.

Thanks in advance!

---------------- UPDATE -----------------

After looking at IValueConverter as Vadim Martynov suggested, I've seen some people who wrapped their Model to handle these situations.
So this is my conclusion:

- When there are one or two view specific properties, just make one or two specific IValueConverter
- When there are several view specific properties, it's best to make a Wrapper (Have a look to this post: [Binding Model properties directly in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809305/binding-model-properties-directly-in-view))

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `IValueConverter` to bind your actual data instead of creating synthetic properties for the view.

For example, you can have `TitleType` enumeration which contains `Title`, `Subtitle` and `Text` elements.

Then write new converter:

```
public class TitleTypeToSeparatorVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var titleType = (TitleType) value;
        switch(titleType)
        {
            case TitleType.Title:
                // return some value
            case TitleType.Subtitle:
                // return some another one value
            default:
                // handle this scenario
        }
    }
}
```

[Read more about `IValueConverter`](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/)

Comment: Very usefull! I knew about IValueConverter, but I didn't think using them this way.  Are they the way to go for every "View issue"? I mean, you never should build a "Model for the View"? (By the way, i'm sorry for my english, as you can see, it's not my first language :p )

Comment: @Speuline you never should build a "Model for the View". Then you have Model class and you need to adjust your View by the data. Views can contains platform specific properties like Visibiliity, Color, Brush and other. You should never use it in ViewModel or Model classes. Then you need to create converter from the data (Model) to the View and bind data properties with its converters. 

Also, you can use data triggers. 

You are adept your view to your model on that way, aren't you?

Comment: @Speuline also it can be bad idea to create property specially for the view, I agree. But you are already have some value that indicates Title level. You can use it and create converter for this already existing property.

Comment: But what if I've 50 properties in my ViewModel, and each of theses properties have their own displaying way into the view, maybe it's better
to build a helper class for the view instead of creating 50 converters, no?